# How does running ASP.Net on Linux compare to the standard Microsoft-centric solution?

Tags: asp.net, .net, linux, mono

I know its possible to develop and host an ASP.Net site on Linux using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com) and [Apache](http://www.apache.org/), but I'd like to know how well it works and if its worth the hassle?  I prefer open source, but for this project I want the quickest, easiest, most reliable solution.

The site I'll be building will be a fairly basic ASP.Net site using [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/).

I'd like to know if anyone else has experience using Mono in a situation like mine and how the project went.  How did it compare to using a Microsoft-centric solution?

I know [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com) is still somewhat incomplete, but I'm hoping I won't need the features it lacks.

This question may be a bit "polarizing".  Most similar questions seem to have responses from people who are either very pro-Microsoft or pro-Linux.  I'm hoping for some unbiased responses, preferably from people with experience using both.

Comment: it really depends on what you mean by simple asp.net site. Are you hosting yourself

Comment: Why not to use something which is more preferable according to your requirements? E.g. Ruby/PHP? Especially if it's going to be a fairly basic web-site (as you said).

Comment: This site is for a roofing company, used to help them calculate estimates.  I will try to make it look reasonably attractive, but functionality is the primary goal.

Comment: As for hosting, I'm thinking of using an Amazon EC2 instance.  Since the number of hits per day will probably be very low, I'm thinking I can get away with using a micro instance, but if necessary it could be bumped-up to a small.

Comment: I have been using Linux (mainly Ubuntu) for several years now, but its largely been a hobby. Most of the development I've done career-wise has been Microsoft-centric, so that's why I want to stick with ASP.Net, since that's what I'm most familiar with.  I'm just hoping to kind of "marry the two" on this project. --also, the Linux Amazon EC2 instances are cheaper.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I switched from MS-centric solutions about a year and a half ago and now I'm hosting all of my websites and web projects on Linux/Mono/Apache/MySQL based virtual servers (I was originally using nginx instead of apache, but mono-fastcgi-server was randomly causing [thrashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)), so I choose apache as a web server). I can summarize my (subjective) experience with this configuration into a few points:

- It can take some time to get used to difference between Linux and MS based environments (if you never used Linux before), but I do not regret this decision. What helped me a lot was creating installation and configuration procedures for particular technologies (for example mono parallel environments, apache virtual hosts configurations, dealing with certain issues) which are mostly repeatable and can be automated.
- You can still use Visual Studio to develop your applications and then deploy them on Linux machine. If you are using this approach it's a good habit to test your apps regularly on mono for possible incompatibilities.
- I deploy web applications via FTP which is probably the easiest way of doing it (well maybe WinSCP is even easier, because you don't have to set up FTP server, but it depends on your preferences).
- So far I have run into 2 cases with Mono/Apache where memory leak caused unavailability of the website. This was probably caused by Boehm garbage collector which I was using on old mono installation. I haven't had similar problems with a new sgen GC on recent versions of mono.
- What I like the most on mono running on Linux environment compared to MS stuff is that you don't have to click around all the time when doing administrative tasks. Shell is for me unified administrative interface which can speed up things (if you have some practice).

Comment: I'm curious, did you notice any difference in site responsiveness when switching from Microsoft to Linux?  Or was it pretty much identical?

Comment: I would say it is identical, but I didn't have a chance to test it with larger traffic yet. However it's a big difference when you want (or need) to scale your systems which can seriously hurt your finances if you are using MS solutions. Also I don't like to be constrained by the number of CPU cores or amount of RAM by the OS license type from MS, so Linux (or open source) based systems are pretty much superior in this area.

Comment: +1 jimbo - financial contraints can be an issue. but if your site(s) start to bring more $$ you can add in a Win2008 Server to the web cluster in a basic load balance setup (F5)... even with MySql clusters. The only problem I have is RavenDB doesn't run well in production on Linux :(

Answer (score 4):

Hosting ASP.NET on mono from my experience is quite easy and fast. i has been host multiple of my project using Mono ASP.NET MVC 1 / 2 using MySQL and PostgreSQL,  serve by Apache mod_mono.

Compared with deployment on Windows Server. It quite narrow when using modern linux distribution which already provides all package to deploy mono ASP.NET. the only drawback is you have to make sure your Web Application portable enough in term of IO accessing and only very short learning curve and experience needed to debug and publish your project.

For Deploying our project in Linux. It easy using Version Control (VS) such as Mercurial or Git if u have fully control on the server. If U have more experience using continues integration is more better. I mainly using mercurial so step bellow is the step i usually do, but i think it almost similar for Git:

- Install mercurial, and configure mod_wsgi, hgweb.wsgi and hgwerb.config
- Init VS repo and publish at hgweb.config and configure hook to update and invoke xbuild to automatically build when u push it
- publish the repo (web part) as mono application at mod_mono.conf
- So u just need to code at visual studio, commit and push your changes using tortoiseHg without event login to server (set repo url, user and password at your repo hgrc)

Comment: my suggestion if u using Amazon EC2 is using openSuSe image generated easily using http://susestudio.com/ as openSuSe support for mono imho is very good

Comment: Thank you.  I've been considering susestudio, although I've never used openSuSe before.

Comment: I was initially thinking susestudio was free, but apparently its not.  How much does it cost, just out of curiosity?

Comment: As far as i know susestudio service is free [FAQ |http://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:SUSE_Studio_Faq#How_much_does_it_cost.3F] u could used without need to create new user to register just used your openid provider account such as gmail and yahoo

Answer (score -2):

Please note that although you can deploy ASP on Linux via things like Mono, if you use a Microsoft ide such as Visual studio, webmatrix, or Visual web developer your licence only allows you to deploy these on Microsoft servers!

Comment: Microsoft EULA does not put such a restriction. Please review them again.