# Is Mono's VB.Net support ready for a production site?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, linux, mono

Previously, I've only used Microsoft-centric solutions, but for an upcoming ASP.Net project I'm considering using Mono and hosting it on a Linux Amazon EC2 instance.  Based on the responses to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738168/how-does-running-asp-net-on-linux-compare-to-the-standard-microsoft-centric-solut), this sounds doable.  However, I'm most comfortable with VB.Net and I'm wondering how well Mono supports it.

Does anyone have first-hand experience writing ASP.Net applications for Mono using VB.Net?  If so, I'd like to know how it went, what kind of compatibility issues you ran into, and if you consider Mono's VB.Net support ready for use on a production site?

I know Mono's C#.Net support is very good, so that's my fall-back plan, but I'd really prefer to use VB.Net.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The VB compiler hasn't been abandoned, it's just a lack of time that is preventing the required work to update to newer VB versions.

Currently vbnc has support for VB 8 (aka Visual Studio 2005), with a few minor features from newer VB versions.

The easiest and safest would be to precompile your site on Windows, in which case you won't have to deal with any potential compiler issues (and you can use the most recent Visual Studio version). If you take this route you shouldn't run into any bugs you wouldn't hit using C# [1]

[1]: You'd be referencing one assembly more: Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll, which *could* be a source of bugs - but if you adhere to what is considered good programming practice for VB (turn on Option Strict) the chances that you'll hit any significant new bugs is pretty low.

Comment: I agree, precompiling is the way to go.  After reading jpobst's post I tried precompiling a small ASP.Net project and hosting it on a Mono-enabled Linux server. --so far, so good!

Comment: If anyone wonders why, I switched the accepted answer from jpobst to Rolf because Rolf mentioned that there is one assembly a VB.Net project requires that C#.Net does not.  I had been wondering why I still needed to install vbnc even when precompiling.  Based on jpobst's answer I didn't think it would be necessary.  Thanks for answering that question, Rolf.

Answer (score 6):

Note that you can also use .Net's precompilation for ASP.Net, and then all the VB.Net is compiled, so it doesn't matter how good or bad Mono's support of VB.Net is.

Precompilation also removes the initial compilation hit when your pages are first hit.

Just another thing to keep in mind as a fallback in case you hit bugs in Mono's VB.Net compiler.

Comment: In fact, I thought this was the *only* way to run something under Mono.  Interesting that they have a VB.NET compiler now.  I will have to check it out.

Comment: The "new" vb compiler (vbnc) is about 4 years old.  There was another one before that.

Comment: Are you assuming that the IL produced from VB is indistinguishable from IL produced by C#? Because that's not 100% true. There are a very few .Net features like [exception filtering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602066/why-doesnt-c-have-support-for-first-pass-exception-filtering) which are not available from C#. The Mono implementation in the .Net framework could be utterly buggy, and they'd never know until you tried to run an assembly built with VB.Net.

Comment: While it may not be 100% true, it is probably 99+% true.  This is coupled with the fact Mono has had a VB.Net compiler and VB.Net runtime for at least 4 years, so this isn't uncharted waters.  The biggest potential issue is that the compiler lags a bit behind the latest VB.Net version (2010), which would be alleviated by using Microsoft's compiler.

Comment: I wondered if pre-compiling was possible, that's sounding like the best solution to me.  So basically, I'd precompile with Visual Studio, then just drop the compiled files on the web server running Mono?  Sounds almost too easy.

Comment: It works!  Although, I still had to install vbnc.  I'm surprised I had to after precompiling, but it wouldn't work until I did.

Answer (score 5):

According to the Mono people, the VB.Net support in Mono is relatively new. However, they contend that it is totally complete and the VB.Net compiler etc. pass all of their unit tests. That does not mean that there won't be bugs, as with anything.

You should most definitely give it a try. VB.Net has complete support in Mono and it shouldn't behave any differently than it would on a Windows machine (though, as always, no guarantees).

Comment: Very true, and I thank you for your response.  However, I'd like to hear from someone who's used it.  I don't want to have the project partly done, only to find I have to translate it all to C#.Net for it to work with Mono.

Comment: Yes, that's my concern, that the Mono VB.Net project may have fallen behind or been abandoned.

Comment: "Relatively new" is relative.  This page is the likely source for this answer: http://www.mono-project.com/VisualBasic.NET_support It references mono 1.2.3 as the starting point and mono 2.6 later on. It's likely the original prose was never updated, and what was once very new is now less so.

Comment: @Joel I think they meant relative to C#. But you're right, that doesn't seem very new.

Answer (score 4):

It does seem that active development and support by the Mono project team continues for VB.NET. The [(draft) release notes](http://mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.10) for the next release, 2.10, includes [an item regarding the VB compiler](http://mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.10#VB_Compiler) which is listed as one of the release's *major* highlights:

> VB Compiler
>
> The VB Compiler (vbnc) has been
>   upgraded to use cecil/light instead of
>   Reflection, which makes it possible to
>   create assemblies with different
>   runtime versions using only 1
>   compiler. That is very similar to the
>   changes that we did to the Mono C#
>   Compiler detailed above.
>
> By default vbnc will now compile to
>   the 4.0 profile, and a new script
>   (vbnc2) has been added to compile to
>   the 2.0 profile.