# VB.NET form on Mono gives me VBNC30451: 'EventArgs' is not declared

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, mono

I'm running Mono 4.2.1.102 together with mono-basic 4.0.1 on FreeBSD 10 (10.1-RELEASE-p10) and I'm in the middle of moving several websites which previously ran on Windows Server 2003. I've had little problems with the C# ones (nothing I couldn't fix myself) but when moving a site made in VB.NET I got this error and it eludes me. Especially because EventArgs is a type and not so much a variable.

I've set up a helloworld test case which consisted of only the .aspx markup and a .aspx.vb codefile and it has only one method:

```
Partial Class HelloWorld
  Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

  Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
      MyBase.OnLoad(e)
  End Sub
End Class
```

The easy solution is of course to port this whole website to C# but considering that Mono is said to support VB.NET I'd really like to know what I'm missing here.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4810093/4984832 from Rolf myself...

Comment: Personally I was involved in a conversion/platform change a while back for a bunch of VB.Net code and while pre-compiled assemblies worked really well, we had no debug/compile cycles on OS-X/Linux as the code based was pass VB8 and thus we could not compile on the OS itself... after awhile of wasted time/money of compile, copy, review failures, guess at code changes, recompile, copy, and repeat, we converted the code to xplat-based C# and everyone was happy (well the VB coders were not...)...

Comment: Rosyln's VB compiler and AST.NET/dnx should be (will be) a great replacement, but dnx is just getting into Release Candidates as a 1.0 product with no debugging support via VSCode just yet...